# How to check user permission in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to find which user has access to which Azure service from Azure Activity Directory.

For example: I want to check, Does abc user has access to Azure app service, billing, VMs or SQL server etc

If owner role is assigned to a User/Group then I assume it can access all the services but if there is no role assigned then is there a way to check which service can be accessed by a user.

Please do let me know if more details are required.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this :

**1. Checking logged in User's self permissions**

You can ask the relevant user to Log into the Azure portal -> Click on the User logo on the top right corner of the screen -> select the elipsis (...) -> select "My permissions".
[image]

This will list all the permissions that user has in the Azure portal.

**2. Checking Access Contrl (IAM) in the resource or resource group / subscription level.**

see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/check-access#step-2-check-access-for-a-user

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rimaz for your response.

I think above two mentioned methods are showing user roles and group permissions, I want to check only specific Azure service which is accessed by specific user.

Also, I want to check the user permissions in bulk (let's say 60 people), on which Azure services they have access to.

Please let me know if more clarity is required.